# error doesn't displaying in logcat android 6.0 - android studio 2.0

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, android-studio-2.0

I making a demo app in the android studio 2.0 using a cellphone that have android 6.0 and forcing an error, but while in my old device running in android logcat display the error :

```
Could not find method increment(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button_plus'
```

In android 6.0 doesn't displat any error just close the app, there is any other config to display the errors? . Thanks a lot.